# ListView Blank not showing db entries

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, cursor, android-logcat

when trying to get my ListView to refresh when my db data changes, my list view in now completely blank. itemare being added to the db but they are no longer being displayed in listview. of all the db columns, only one was set to display in listview (sname). My Logcat points to a requery but Im not sure how to proceed with a fix. Please advise.

Logcat:

```
   02-19 22:41:41.303: W/SQLiteCursor(1083): requery() failed database /data/data/com.loginplus.home/databases/SiteLogindb (conn# 0) already closed
   02-19 22:41:41.303: W/SQLiteCursor(1083): java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.loginplus.home/databases/SiteLogindb (conn# 0) already closed
   02-19 22:41:41.303: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2082)
   02-19 22:41:41.303: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getDbConnection(SQLiteDatabase.java:2407)
   02-19 22:41:41.303: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getDatabaseHandle(SQLiteDatabase.java:2388)
   02-19 22:41:41.303: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.requery(SQLiteCursor.java:246)
   02-19 22:41:41.303: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:4505)
   02-19 22:41:41.303: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4531)
   02-19 22:41:41.303: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
  02-19 22:41:41.303: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
   02-19 22:41:41.303: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1173)
   02-19 22:41:41.303: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   02-19 22:41:41.303: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   02-19 22:41:41.303: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
   02-19 22:41:41.303: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   02-19 22:41:41.303: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   02-19 22:41:41.303: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
   02-19 22:41:41.303: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
   02-19 22:41:41.303: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   02-19 22:41:41.323: W/SQLiteCursor(1083): requery() failed database /data/data/com.loginplus.home/databases/SiteLogindb (conn# 0) already closed
   02-19 22:41:41.323: W/SQLiteCursor(1083): java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.loginplus.home/databases/SiteLogindb (conn# 0) already closed
   02-19 22:41:41.323: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2082)
   02-19 22:41:41.323: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getDbConnection(SQLiteDatabase.java:2407)
   02-19 22:41:41.323: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getDatabaseHandle(SQLiteDatabase.java:2388)
   02-19 22:41:41.323: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.requery(SQLiteCursor.java:246)
   02-19 22:41:41.323: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:4505)
   02-19 22:41:41.323: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4531)
   02-19 22:41:41.323: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
   02-19 22:41:41.323: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
   02-19 22:41:41.323: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1173)
   02-19 22:41:41.323: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   02-19 22:41:41.323: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   02-19 22:41:41.323: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
   02-19 22:41:41.323: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   02-19 22:41:41.323: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   02-19 22:41:41.323: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
   02-19 22:41:41.323: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
   02-19 22:41:41.323: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   02-19 22:41:41.343: W/SQLiteCursor(1083): requery() failed database /data/data/com.loginplus.home/databases/SiteLogindb (conn# 0) already closed
   02-19 22:41:41.343: W/SQLiteCursor(1083): java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.loginplus.home/databases/SiteLogindb (conn# 0) already closed
   02-19 22:41:41.343: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2082)
   02-19 22:41:41.343: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getDbConnection(SQLiteDatabase.java:2407)
   02-19 22:41:41.343: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getDatabaseHandle(SQLiteDatabase.java:2388)
   02-19 22:41:41.343: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.requery(SQLiteCursor.java:246)
   02-19 22:41:41.343: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:4505)
   02-19 22:41:41.343: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4531)
   02-19 22:41:41.343: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
  02-19 22:41:41.343: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
  02-19 22:41:41.343: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1173)
  02-19 22:41:41.343: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  02-19 22:41:41.343: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  02-19 22:41:41.343: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
  02-19 22:41:41.343: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  02-19 22:41:41.343: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  02-19 22:41:41.343: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
  02-19 22:41:41.343: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
  02-19 22:41:41.343: W/SQLiteCursor(1083):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Logcat 2/2513

```
   02-24 20:44:04.032: E/AndroidRuntime(1323): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.loginplus.home/com.loginplus.home.LoginList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
   02-24 20:44:04.032: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
   02-24 20:44:04.032: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
   02-24 20:44:04.032: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
   02-24 20:44:04.032: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
   02-24 20:44:04.032: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   02-24 20:44:04.032: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   02-24 20:44:04.032: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
   02-24 20:44:04.032: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   02-24 20:44:04.032: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   02-24 20:44:04.032: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
   02-24 20:44:04.032: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
   02-24 20:44:04.032: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   02-24 20:44:04.032: E/AndroidRuntime(1323): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   02-24 20:44:04.032: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):  at com.loginplus.home.LoginList.populateList(LoginList.java:92)
   02-24 20:44:04.032: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):  at com.loginplus.home.LoginList.onCreate(LoginList.java:41)
   02-24 20:44:04.032: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
   02-24 20:44:04.032: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
   02-24 20:44:04.032: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

activity class:

```
  public class LoginList extends Activity implements OnClickListener,    OnItemClickListener {

  private ListView loginList;
  private Button webLogin;

  private ListAdapter loginListAdapter;

  private ArrayList<LoginDetails> loginArrayList;

  List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();



 @Override 
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 arrayList = populateList();
 loginListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
 setContentView(R.layout.login_listview);


 loginList = (ListView)
 findViewById(R.id.loginlist);
 loginList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

 webLogin = (Button)
 findViewById(R.id.button3);
 webLogin.setOnClickListener(this);


 }

@Override
public void onClick (View v) {
Intent webLoginIntent = new Intent (this, LoginPlusActivity.class);
startActivity(webLoginIntent);

}

public List<String> populateList (){

List<String> webNameList = new ArrayList<String>();

dataStore openHelperClass = new dataStore (this);

SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = openHelperClass.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE, null, null, null,  null, null, dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_SITE, null);

//startManagingCursor(cursor); (revised 2/25/13)


while (cursor.moveToNext()){
String sName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_SITE));
String wUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS));
String uName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME));
String pWord = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD));
String lNotes = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_NOTES));

LoginDetails lpDetails = new LoginDetails();

  lpDetails.setsName(sName);
  lpDetails.setwUrl(wUrl);
  lpDetails.setuName(uName);
  lpDetails.setpWord(pWord);
  lpDetails.setlNotes(lNotes);

  loginArrayList.add(lpDetails);
  webNameList.add(sName);
 }

 cursor.close(); //(revised 2/25/13)
 return webNameList;
 }



@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();

ArrayList<LoginDetails> loginArrayList = new ArrayList<LoginDetails>();
loginArrayList.clear();

arrayList.clear();

arrayList = populateList();

dataStore refreshHelper = new dataStore (this);
SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = refreshHelper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE, null, null, null, null, null, dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_SITE, null);
String[]columns = new String[] { dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_SITE,    dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS, dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME,  dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD, dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_NOTES };
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.rusName, R.id.ruwUrl, R.id.ruuName, R.id.rupWord, R.id.ruNotes};
SimpleCursorAdapter loginListAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, columns, to);
loginListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0 , View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected ID :" + arg2,     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 Intent updateDeleteLoginInfo = new Intent (this, UpdateDeleteLoginList.class);



 LoginDetails clickedObject = loginArrayList.get(arg2);

  Bundle loginBundle = new Bundle();
  loginBundle.putString("clickedWebSite",clickedObject.getsName());
  loginBundle.putString("clickedWebAddress",clickedObject.getwUrl());
  loginBundle.putString("clickedUserName",clickedObject.getuName());
  loginBundle.putString("clickedPassWord",clickedObject.getpWord());
  loginBundle.putString("clickedNotes",clickedObject.getlNotes());

  updateDeleteLoginInfo.putExtras(loginBundle);

  startActivityForResult(updateDeleteLoginInfo, 0);   
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the problem is in this line `startManagingCursor(cursor);`. You are asking the activity to manage the cursor but you close the connection right after you are done with the cursor. Just comment that line out and also close the cursor instead of the database. Just change `sqliteDatabase.close();` to `cursor.close()`.

Comment: applied changes and now receive a new logcat error on line 92: loginArrayList.add(lpDetails); and line 41: arrayList = populateList(); see new posted logcat and revised code

Comment: Your `loginArrayList` is null. You are calling `arrayList = populateList();` inside your `onCreate` method but you don't initialize it anywhere. In `onResume`, which takes place after `onCreate` is done, you create a local variable `loginArrayList` that overwrites the `loginArrayList` instance variable in that scope. I'd suggest you either initialize your `loginArrayList` instance variable before calling `populate()` in `onCreate` or remove your `populate()` call from `onCreate` and just use `loginArrayList = new ArrayList<LoginDetails>();` in `onResume`.